# VBA: passing parameter into access query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have access DB and few queries there.

Recently I have added an option group with two radio buttons(values: 1 and 2) to my form.

What I try to achieve is: when first radio button is checked queries should return data only for countries; when second one is checked queries should return only data for cities.

I created some code:

```
Private Sub Command54_Click()

Dim dtps As String

If Frame45.Value = 1 Then
    dtps = "101,103,1104,1105"  
Else
    dtps = "105,125,127,129,131,133,145,147,149,151,153,171,173,175,177,179,181,1105,1125,1127,1129,1131,1133,1141,1145,1147,1149,1151,1153,104,124,126,128,130,132,144,146,148,150,152,170,172,172,176,178,180,1104,1124,1126,1128,1130,1132,1144,1146,1146,1148,1150,1152"
End If


DoCmd.OpenQuery "test1", acViewNormal, acEdit

End Sub
```

Right now query "test1" is very simple:

```
"Select * from MyTable"
```

And my idea is to change it to :

```
  "Select * from MyTable Where CountryCodeID IN  ( @dtps )"
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

---

What I also tried is to use function:

My Query code:

```
Select * from MyTable Where CountryCodeID IN  ( getcountrycode() )
```

Function code is:

```
Private Sub Command54_Click()

'MsgBox Frame45.Value

DoCmd.OpenQuery "test1", acViewNormal, acEdit

End Sub

Public Function getcountrycode()

Dim dtps As String

If Frame45.Value = 1 Then
    dtps = "101,103,1104,1105"
Else
    dtps = "101,103,105,125,127,129,131,133,145,147,149,151,153,171,173,175,177,179,181,1105,1125,1127,1129,1131,1133,1141,1145,1147,1149,1151,1153,104,124,126,128,130,132,144,146,148,150,152,170,172,172,176,178,180,1104,1124,1126,1128,1130,1132,1144,1146,1146,1148,1150,1152"
End If

getcountrycode = dtps

End Function
```

It returns error:  "Undefined function 'getcountrycode' in expression

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to simply build the query:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable Where CountryCodeID IN ( " & dtps & " )"

If Not IsNull(DLookup( _
    "Test1", "MSysObjects", "[Name]='Test1' AND Type= 5")) Then
    ''Query exists, overwrite the sql permanently
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Test1").SQL = sSQL
Else
    ''Note that you cannot have a query with the same name as a table, 
    ''so you might need to check that, too.
    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "Test1", sSQL
End If

DoCmd.OpenQuery "test1", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

Rather than simply opening a query, I strongly suggest you bind the query to a form.